# SELECT WHERE id IN X, X, Xonly one result

Tags: php

i have the following query:

```
$sql_select_todo = 
                  "SELECT * FROM 
                               to_do_items 
                            WHERE
                               id_project = ".$_SESSION['selected_projectId']."'
                            AND 
                               id IN ('".$alleTaken."')";

$query_select_todo = mysql_query($sql_select_todo) or die(mysql_error());

while($fetch_todo = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_select_todo))  {

    echo $fetch_todo['name'];
}
```

When i echo the query, i get this:

```
SELECT * FROM to_do_items WHERE id_project = '7401' AND id IN ('10193,12848')
```

But the output will only give back one name `($fetch_todo['name'])`

But there are 2 id's, so i should get 2 names. What do i do wrong here?

Comment: Remove single quote in IN query eg `id IN (".$alleTaken.")";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove single quote in IN query

Change

```
$sql_select_todo = 
                  "SELECT * FROM 
                               to_do_items 
                            WHERE
                               id_project = ".$_SESSION['selected_projectId']."'
                            AND 
                               id IN ('".$alleTaken."')";
```

To

```
$sql_select_todo = 
                  "SELECT * FROM 
                               to_do_items 
                            WHERE
                               id_project = ".$_SESSION['selected_projectId']."'
                            AND 
                               id IN (".$alleTaken.")";
```

Comment: Thank you verry much, that is the solution!